# JPA CriteriaUpdate join self table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria-api

I have this sentence in plain SQL that I'm trying to implement in Java JPA.

```
UPDATE table t1, table t2
SET
    t1.field1 = t2.field1,
    t1.field2 = t2.field2
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND t1.field3 = t2.field3
    AND t1.field4 = t2.field4
;
```

Basically is a self join by several fields and a update of others.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@XmlRootElement
public class Table implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    public Table(){}

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I try to implement in my method:

```
[...]
CriteriaBuilder builder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Table> cu = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Table.class);

Root<Table> t1 = cu.from(Table.class);
Root<Table> t2 = cu.from(Table.class);

Predicate p1 = builder.equal(t1.get(Table_.field3), t2.get(Table_.field3));
Predicate p2 = builder.equal(t1.get(Table_.field4), t2.get(Table_.field4));

cu.where(builder.and(p1, p2));

cu.set(t1.get(Table_.field1), t2.get(Table_.field1));
cu.set(t1.get(Table_.field2), t2.get(Table_.field2));

Query queryUpdate = this.em.createQuery(cu);
int ret = query.executeUpdate();


[...]
```

But the result is always 0 rows altered, besides there are few rows that should be modified.

Somebody has faced something similar.

Any idea will be very helpful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: and the entity(s) classes are ? i.e what relations exist?

Comment: And where are ur joins ?? It must be either explicitly declared or relations must be declared.

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton Stockton, the entity is just Table. Let's say that is a sigle class: `code` public class Table{ private String field1; private String field2;private String field3; private String field4; // getters and setters }

Comment: Hi @antoniossss, there are no joins! It's de same entity, without relations with other tables.

Comment: so if you are not using O-O. with relations etc, and just want to update a database, then use a NATIVE update.

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton, so there's no way to do it through JPA? In the case that there were relations, but should modify some of the fields of this table, how should I proceed?

Comment: if there were relations then you use Criteria "join" method to JOIN.

Comment: The JPA query should still work, what is the SQL that gets generated?

Comment: Hi @Chris, the SQL is: UPDATE table SET field1 = field1, field2 = field2 WHERE ( (field3 = field3) AND (field4 = field4)); Seems to me that there is no distinction between table t1 and table t2. And maybe that's why there is no rows modified.

Comment: I am mistaken; the spec states "Only one entity abstract schema type may be specified in the FROM or UPDATE clause.".  This means that your query is still possible, but requires a more complex subselects to handle the obtaining each of the values from the second table.  Neil is correct that you are better off with a native SQL query here.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thank you for your comment. I already have solved the problem through a native query, but I'll try to figure out an alternative in order to be independent of the SQL database. In this case I have done it with MySQL, but perhaps in Oracle it would not work...